# In javafx table view doesn't display

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

[image: Refer Image of Output]
//Database is Sucessfully Connected 
I am trying to Create a table in which I want to display the contents of my 'student' table in tableView of Javafx but I could not get the desired output.

```
ObservableList<Student> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
//Initializes the controller class.
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
{
    // TODO
    initCol();
    loadTable();
}

//A view Table has been made with fx:id-table
//Variable name for 2 columns are 'fx:id-rollnoColand' & 'fx:id-nameCol'

@FXML
private TableView<Student> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Student,String> rollnoCol;    
@FXML
private TableColumn<Student,String> nameCol;

private void initCol()
{
    rollnoCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("s_rollno"));
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("s_name"));
}

//Name of the Table is 'student' with Columns 'rollno' and 'name'

private void loadTable()
{
    String selectAll = "select * from student"; 
    try
    {
        Statement stmt = connectdb.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectAll); 

        while(rs.next())
        {
            String getrollno = rs.getString("rollno");
            String getname = rs.getString("name"); 

            list.add(new Student(getrollno,getname));
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException exp)
    {
        System.out.println(exp);
    }        

    table.getItems().setAll(list);
}

public static class Student
{
    private final String s_rollno;
    private final String s_name;

    Student(String rollno,String name)
    {
        this.s_rollno = rollno;
        this.s_name = name;           
    }

}
```

Comment: PropertyValueFactory only works with properties or getters. Fields are not loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropertyValueFactory` works with getters or property methods. In your case you need to add getters for your properties in the `Student` class to enable `PropertyValueFactory` to retrieve the values:

```
public static class Student {

    private final String s_rollno;
    private final String s_name;

    Student(String rollno, String name) {
        this.s_rollno = rollno;
        this.s_name = name;
    }

    public String getS_rollno() {
        return s_rollno;
    }

    public String getS_name() {
        return s_name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem before,and it has many reason.First ,you may remove `final` keyword from your model,because your variables are changing.Second, TableView shows empty cells because you make your variables `private` in class `Student` and you can not access them from `init method` in parent class.So you need add  getter and setter methods for access to these variables.

```
public static class Student
{
    private  String s_rollno;
    private  String s_name;

    Student(String rollno,String name)
    {
        this.s_rollno = rollno;
        this.s_name = name;           
    }

 public String getS_rollno() {
        return s_rollno;
    }

    public void setS_rollno(String s_rollno) {
        this.s_rollno = s_rollno;
    }

    public String getS_name() {
        return s_name;
    }

    public void setS_name(String s_name) {
        this.s_name = s_name;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no indication that the OP needs mutable `Student` objects. Furthermore you can access `private` members of inner classes from the enclosing class, it's just that `PropertyValueFactory` does not work this way...

Comment: @fabian but we remove getter and setter we don't get any result,how you can explain this ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine `PropertyValueFactory` uses getters or property methods to retrieve the values. It never works with the fields directly whether the access would be possible or not. Furthermore the access from the init method is irrelevant, but the claim that a private member of a inner class cannot be accessed from the eclosing class is simply wrong. You could use a anonymus class/lambda expression as a `cellValueFactory` that only uses `private` members of `Student` and it would work.